# Exception while executing maven Spring web mvc in web.xml

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

Getting below exception after running code while using spring mvc and maven dependency management. Can anybody please help ? Checked answers on links below

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572773/java-lang-illegalstateexception-beanfactory-not-initialized-or-already-closed)

[Spring security configuration: IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354766/spring-security-configuration-illegalstateexception-beanfactory-not-initialize)

[BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114955/beanfactory-not-initialized-or-already-closed-call-refresh-before)

[BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344762/beanfactory-not-initialized-or-already-closed-call-refresh-before-accessing)

but nothing worked.

```
Mar 01, 2016 4:58:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:109)
    ... 16 more

Mar 01, 2016 4:58:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 01, 2016 4:58:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/m] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 01, 2016 4:58:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 01, 2016 4:58:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:993)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Mar 01, 2016 4:58:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

**web.xml file -**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">
  <display-name>MongoSample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>    
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>

    <mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**" cache-period="1314000"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" cache-period="1314000"/>

    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
        <property name="port" value="27017"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean> 

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>HiberM</groupId>
  <artifactId>m</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>m Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>m</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Have executed/run the application without using maven by adding jars to lib folder it worked fine, but when using maven it is throwing this exception. MI checked maven dependencies to the deployment assembly and they are present in that location.I am a beginner to maven. If any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason for these kind of errors is that you import multiple versions of same classes through Maven, either directly or through dependencies, so the wrong one is chosen from classpath in runtime.
Or you imported some servlet classes already provided by Tomcat container.
Try to exclude some of the artifacts from dependencies. Or here is servlet dependency I use, and it works without any problems with similar configuration as yours.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```